# how to size up divs to fill all space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bar-chart

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bar {
            background-color:red;
            height:100%;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid black;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>        
    <div class="bar"></div>        
    <div class="bar"></div>                
</body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                 var count = 7;
                 var divs = $('.bar');
                 for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                    $(divs[i]).width((100/count) +'%');
                 }
            }); 
    </script>
```

one of the bars in the above output goes below the first one, i.e. not all bar
accomodate in one line, how do I do that ? is it possible ?

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/XEGNE/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need JS for this at all. A better solution would be to do something like:

```
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;    
}

.bar {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

see example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/anfgD

Comment: This is wrong. It does not fill whole page. See my example filling WHOLE PAGE: http://jsbin.com/eYUDUTa/2

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I made a very minor changes to the JS, then I set the parent of `.bar` to `100%`, which will force it to take up `100%`, as it had been set to `100%` of nothing - which is `0`.

Additionally, using `box-sizing` will force the `borders` to be calculated into the `width`/`height` of the `divs`.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9GqL/)

**Updated JS** - *note the changes..*

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 7;
    var divs = $('.bar');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        $(divs[i]).width((100 / count - 2) + '%');
    }
});
```

**Updated CSS**

```
.bar {
     background-color:red;
     height:100%;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid black;
     float:left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works. it also works though without setting body and html height. I am bit confused though (100/7-2) results in 12.xx the rendered html has width set to 14.xx.... And why would you subtract 2 ?

Comment: @JohnSmith Actually, it doesn't working if you don't set the height on body/html.. see http://jsfiddle.net/J9GqL/1/ .. as for the JS, I honestly don't know - trial and error.

Comment: ok, i think that is the right way. it worked on a webpage i was trying out though.

Answer (score 0):

The border is causing the width to exceed 100%, forcing the last block onto the next line.

You can safely add to fix this:

```
* (box-sizing:border-box;)
```

see http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: - i don't know about border-box, will read it up.
- but, above code works as expected if I take out "border", if I keep border it doesn't work even if i use box-sizing.

Comment: box-sizing is related to padding, not border. box-sizing does not have anything to do with the borders.

Comment: no - border is included. see the graphic here : http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: Somebody suggested this edit: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3157732

It was rejected, but looked like it might be adding information of value. I don't have the expertise to judge, though. You might wish to take a look at it and see if you want to implement any of the suggested changes.

Comment: No, border is not included. Try it, you'll see.

Comment: we may be saying the same thing here, from a different angle. border does not *add* to the width.

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser added a horizontal padding to the width, you need to use the box-sizing hack.

Oh, also, subtract 2, not one. Because even though 1px border, well the combined 1px left border, and the 1px right border, the total border width is 2px not 1px. Updated the js.

**See this working jsbin:**
http://jsbin.com/eYUDUTa/2/

**The code (same as the jsbin):**

**page.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>        
    <div class="bar"></div>        
    <div class="bar"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
    body, html {
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;
        padding: 0;
    }        
    .bar {
        background-color:green;
        height:100%;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
        float:left;
    }
    * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 7;
    var divs = $('.bar');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        $(divs[i]).width((100 / count - 2) + '%');
    }
});
```

Comment: btw, that subtract part gets converted to percentages ?

Comment: @JohnSmith What? No it works perfectly! Did you even look at the jsbin?

Comment: @JohnSmith also I updated my jsbin to have height 100%. Also, you do realize that the solution I came up with is the exact same one as the answer that you chose as best answer??

Comment: I was curious about the computation that is done .width((100 / count - 2) + '%'); shouldn't it result to .width('12.28%') instead of .width('14.28%') in case count = 7 ? which also implies.. more the count, more is the white space left out.. but that doesn't happen